# How to calculate in previous week how many sessions market open

Tags: optimization, pivot, offset, pine-script, biweekly

I am trying to calculate offset for next trading week

Problem 
my market open 5 day in week
Problem starting when holiday in market my offset calcution goes wrong

I want when previous week only 3 trading session and next week 5 trading session my offset ploting for next week on calculatation previous week

Comment: Can you supply us with your coding attempts?

Comment: Period== '5' ? 75*5 : 0

Comment: W_shift =period == '5' ? 75*5 :
         period == '15' ? 25*5 :
         period == '30' ? 13*5 :
         period == '45' ? 9*5 :
         period == '60' ? 7*5 :
         period == '240' ? 2*5 :
         0

Comment: i want 75*5 change in to monday to friday